# Logical error in Armstrong number Program

Tags: c

**Problem**-To print armstrong number between 100 to 500.

**Logical error**-Code is not printing any output.

Compiled using codeblocks ide.

```
int a,n,i,j,c;
for(j=100;j<=500;j++)   
{
   int d=0;
   n=100;
   a=n;     //assigning a to n as its value will be changed everytime the loop runs.

     for(i=1;i<=3;i++)   //loop will run corresponds to 3 digit of the number.  
     {
     c=a%10;
     a=a/10;

     d=d+c*c*c;

     }

      // checking if the number = original number
     if(d==n)       
     printf("%d armstrong no\n",d);
      //incrementing the number to increase its value after each loop execution
     n++; 

}
```

Comment: One issue would be that you increment n and the next loop you assign 100 to it, losing what you incremented.You could put that `n = 100` outside the for loop.

Comment: Actually you don't need `n` variable at all. 1.) Instead of `a=n;` -> `a=j;` 2.) Instead of `if(d==n)` -> `if(d==j)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n=100;` is inside the for loop, everytime, n will thus be = to `100`. it should be outside for loop.